# VS2010 Setup Project: Can't create shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, shortcut

I have created a a Setup Project for my application in VS2010. I used the Primary Output from my application-project to add it to the Setup Project, but I can't figure out how to add a shortcut.

I used the right-click -> create new shortcut -> application folder -> Primary Output to create a shortcut.

This didn't generate any compile-errors, but when I use the installer on a Client-PC the shortcut doesn't work.
Even though I set an icon for the shortcut in VS, the icon is just a document now. When I click the shortcut it open the "Preparing Windows Installer"-dialog, which I then cancel. I have to go to the Program Files-folder to run my application.

Comment: Hard to repro these steps, this is baked-in with a single context menu item.  What *exactly* do you right-click?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your installer doesn't install all resources. This would explain why the shortcut in invalid. Perhaps this will help you find the problem: http://setupanddeployment.com/general-installation-problems/preparing-install-popping/

Comment: Is I understand it from the site you provided my installer/installed application is most likely corrupted. However. The program runs just fine when started directly from the folder in Program Files. I therefor think, that it is the installer that causes the problems/is corrupted!

Comment: Just because it works it doesn't mean the installation was successful. The automatic repair is performed for a reason.

Comment: I got the shortcut to work, but adding an icon screws the application pretty much up. The icon on the shortcut isn't changed, and if I start the program directly from Program Files the standard app-icon is showed in the taskbar. The actual exe-file has the correct icon.